# Is there a way to store vertex positions in a UV set?

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices

I'd like to set a secondary UV set to store the object space vertex positions. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Like, bake the object/world coordinates to an image texture using a different UV map?

Comment: Nope. Like saving the 3D vertex position to a secondary UV coord. UV1 would be the texture mapping, and UV2 would have vertex positions.

Comment: Could you possibly add an example to your question? I don't quite understand what you're looking for.

Comment: It's pretty simple. If a vertex's position is (0.0, 1.0, 3.0), i want to save that value to that vertex's second UV channel. So, instead of UV2 holding a 2D texture coordinate, I want it to store a 3D position.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. In UV space, there are only 2 axes to store positional vertex data: the U axis and the V axis. The only way to fit 3D into 2D is to project it.

Comment: Is blender only capable of storing 2D information in texture coords? It's very common for game engines to use texture coords for all sorts of additional vertex information.

Comment: Afaik, that's how it is in Blender. Perhaps you should post a question that describes your overarching goal.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/205342/86891

Comment: You can store it, but you need to use 2 additional UV maps, because each contains only 2D data.  You can store X+Y position in one map and Z position in another map.  This is easily enough done with a project-from-view operation from aligned, ortho views.

Answer (score 0):

Sure with Blender3.0~newer with Geo modifier. You can store any data you want to UV2~UV8

Comment: Sorry, In Bleder it can only store Vector2 data in UV channels. So maybe you have to store the Vector4 data to uv2+uv3. It's possibel

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.